# ti.map permissions on Android 6.0.0

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

The sample app on
https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/appc-sample-geocoder
crashes on the initial startup due to missing permissions. I couldn't figure out how to prevent this behaviour. Any ideas? Subsequent startups are ok after granting the permissions.

```
[ERROR] TiApplication: (main) [704,705] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION; Titanium 6.0.0,2016/11/13 01:23,undefined
[ERROR] TiApplication: java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at maps.ad.t.c(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at xj.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:274)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.setMyLocationEnabled(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at ti.map.TiUIMapView.setUserLocationEnabled(TiUIMapView.java:281)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at ti.map.TiUIMapView.processMapProperties(TiUIMapView.java:190)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at ti.map.TiUIMapView.onMapReady(TiUIMapView.java:162)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at zu.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at maps.ad.t$5.run(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
[ERROR] AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

The resulting AndroidManifest.xml contains the permissions [UPDATE]:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.appcelerator.sample.mapping" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="2.0.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/appicon" android:label="Geocoder" android:name="GeocoderApplication" android:debuggable="false" android:theme="@style/appcelerator">
        <activity android:name=".GeocoderActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiTranslucentActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent"/>
        <activity android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.android.TiPreferencesActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize"/>
        <service android:name="com.appcelerator.aps.APSAnalyticsService" android:exported="false"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyBDuTWLdPRaKN2eTTQKVc-QDNdCS6RxzPM"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
    <permission android:name="com.appcelerator.sample.mapping.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.appcelerator.sample.mapping.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

Titanium 6.0.0.GA, Android Version on device: 6.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

So for getting location from marshmallow device you need to show system pop up for user to request specific permission

This link help you to understand 'Requesting Permissions at Run Time'.
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: The app requests for permission during runtime/startup but it crashes before hand (the popup remains and the user may grant the permission). The subsequent startup doesn't crash.

Comment: Your logcat showing that you have not added 'ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION' these two permissions to permissions array.

 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_GET_LOCATION);

Comment: be aware, this app is Titanium, not Java. For permissions @paddel10 follow this flow: https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/appc-sample-ti510/blob/master/app/controllers/permissions.js

Comment: @RenePot thank you. I think I figured it out. The problem is that the View containing the module ti.map is created before the permissions are requested (due to Alloy).

Answer (score 0):

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Add these permissions in your Manifiest

Comment: Thanks, see my edit in the original post. The manifest contains the permissions after the build

Comment: please post your Mainfiest file

Comment: Are You Working On Google Map?